# notify someone about a document i have changed?

Tags: document-library, office-365

This might be a stupid question, but how can I notify someone easily about a document I have changed?

Lets say we have site where 10 users already have full control . we have 2000+ documents. I change an old document and would like to notify 2 of the 10 users, to give me some feedback...

1. In the document library, i can select the document and press share. this also adds unique permission to the document even if the user has full control already.
2. use the Get link option, but this is a lot of mouse clicks and I will move out of SharePoint context to paste the link into an email or similar. seems very cumbersome to me.

Hope you have some good idea.

Best Regards,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set up alert on the document - setting up appropriate options, when you change the document it will send out a notification to all users you have (or if they have set up the alert on the item themselves) specified.

[Create an alert or subscribe to an RSS feed](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/Create-an-alert-or-subscribe-to-an-RSS-feed-e5a79e7b-a146-46da-a9ef-d65409ba8918)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was hoping for a more elegant solution to this. In large teamsites i would not want everyone to know about every change. nor do i want to setup alerts prior to making a change. just a button that says "hey have  a look at this document", without any effort

Comment: Hi there, I think you can pick who gets notified as you set up the alert, don't have to notify everyone under the teamsite :) If you want to have functionality as you described, Custom Ribbon Action and javascript if you somehow manage to get e-mail sent that way. It does sound like a bit of custom development to meet your requirements as they are :)

Comment: Hi, and thanks for your comment. As i have also search the web some more about this, and can see that other has the same need. I will add this to the SharePoint Uservoice section.\

Comment: Perfect, could you also select my post as answer, please?